# Preventing Users from Seeing Old Data MySQL/iOS

Tags: ios, mysql

I'm using an app that allows users to upload and download pics. Similar to snapchat they can view the pics of those they follow. After 24 hrs these pics will be moved to an archive table so users will no longer be able to see them. I'm accomplishing this aspect with mysql partitions.

However, on the client side I need to continuously update the mysql query with the date of the last gotten row from the photos table. I store this date on the iOS app. This becomes problematic if the users logs out and allows someone else to log in. I have to clear this data and have not reference point for either user now.

I have a solution to get around this and I want to know how feasible it is. I would create a trigger that would run each time a user retrieved photos. It would update a column on the users table that would hold the last date they viewed. That way when any user logs back in I will have a reference to that last date they viewed. Is this a good idea? I'm open to any suggestions on how to better this approach seeing as how I need to save the pictures instead of just deleting them.

*note the partitions would work but because I need to ensure photos last a minimum of 24 hrs some photos end up lasting more than 24hrs providing the possibility that a users can still see the photos

Photos Table

*id: binary 16

*users_id: foreign: binary 16

*filename: varchar

*created_at: datetime

The photos are stored on Amazon s3

Comment: does the 24 hour clock start when uploaded or when the user first looks at it

Comment: the clock starts when uploaded

Comment: if you are enduring the storage cost then why don't you let them see it whenever they want to

Comment: Age them off and use pagination

Comment: @DrewPierce I endure the photos so the current user can still see the photos they uploaded. What do you mean by age them off?

Comment: I am no social media expert. but my assumption is on a system like Facebook that I can see your timeline entries for a while. if I go away for a weekend and all your stuff goes away from my visibility then I could think you never post anything

Comment: so aging something off could be anything older than a week is gone from my visibility but the original user can still see it

Comment: in theory you don't need an archive table just a flag

Comment: They way i'm achieving this is through saving the last created_at dat from the last row retrieved and using this is the mysql query. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: MySQL triggers are only on UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE, not SELECT; so it would need to run after some other (potentially minimally related) record were generated/updated, which can make for a convoluted design.

Comment: @DrewPierce technically, if he storing an upload datetime/timestamp, he doesn't even need an archive flag.

Comment: @Uueerdo i don't recommend an archive flag. but rather a visible flag.

Comment: @DrewPierce six of one, half dozen of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column

```
visible int not null
```

Set visible to 1 on upload.
Also put now() into created_at datetime.

Create an event see below:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Have event run daily or every 6 hours, whatever. Can be cron task instead.

When that thing runs it sets visible to 0 for anything over 1 day old.

When users see someone elses profile pictures they see only visible=1 pictures.

The guy that posted the picture sees all his pictures.

So it is automated and you can be asleep at the switch.

Comment: I don't dispute that the flag is even necessary

Comment: But by having code run, you may choose to have things visible for N days for active uploaders, but longer (at least one picture) for Grandma user that makes 1 upload a year. You want your site not to look DEAD afterall

Comment: How well would this scale if I wanted Ti run an event every hour? Bc even running every 6 hours wouldn't ensure the photo only lasted 24 hrs

Comment: People run events every minute. If you add to your question some sizing info we can speculate better. Also info on where the pictures are stored (file system, blob) plus hardware

Comment: We haven't even spoken about schema. Index or composite index including created_at would make it snappy

Comment: Question edited, and would want this to scale for at least a million photos on the table

Comment: 1 million per day are new and need archived/aged/made visible to owner only? Need more detail than 1M

Comment: 1 M max forever with over 1day visible only to owner?

Comment: Sorry abt that, yes 1 million uploaded photos a day. Ideally I would like to archive the photos to keep as much space on the photos table as possible for current photos older than a day

Comment: Insert/delete 42k of your thin rows / hour is piece of cake for these engines. Have index on `created_at`

Comment: I appreciate the help, this is the solution im going with, I have another question: how does the MySQL event affect the time it takes for another query to run?

Comment: Brian it kicks off a chunk of sql statements. they can be as long as your arm like a `stored proc`. So that question is no different than a general question like "How does mysql deal with concurrency and multi-user" and to that I would speculate threading and filesystem mutexes and locks. If I were to write it, it would be thru Akka ! So, it is not a special blocking event that gets exclusive timeslice, just a trigger so to speak (bad word) to start a script.